# Printing Connectivity with my Modem

Tags: network, wifi, printing

I have an MacBook Pro using OS Sierra version 10.12.5 (along with our iPhones & iPad) wirelessly connected to the Arris 6900 Modem-Router and wirelessly connected to our Brother printer. The problem is being able to print to the Brother printer on an every day basis. I can print from any device one minute, wait an hour or two and can't print. What is the problem with the connectivity issues to the printer.  I've checked with our Cox internet provider, help people at Brother, and with the people at Arris. No one has a solution that works. I hate to buy a new modem-router but is that my only choice with this Arris product.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified your Brother printer, but there is a known issue that affects how some of Brother's printers communicate with macOS systems. When I say it's a *known* issue, you'll be hard pressed to find it documented in writing, although you will have this confirmed if you get the right Brother support person on the phone.

There are some workarounds you can try, but these are not guaranteed to work 100% of the time. The only option I've found that will work 100% of the time (based on my experience with a **limited** number of networks using Brother printers), is to disable [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) snooping. However, if your modem/router does not provide configuration settings for [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol), then you'll have to purchase one that does.

So, your options are:

- Disable [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) snooping if your modem/router supports this
- Try connecting to the Brother printer using CUPS (i.e. do not use AirPrint when you add the printer to macOS)
- Use your modem/router to allocate a static IP address to the printer (using the printer's MAC Address<sup>1</sup> to identify it) and also configuring the printer's network settings to give it the IP address you've set at the modem/router end
- Connect the printer via USB cable instead of Wi-Fi to your MBP when printing

If you still get no joy, then your best bet (assuming you want to keep using the Brother printer) is to purchase a modem/router that supports [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) and ensure you disable [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) snooping.

Regardless of what you opt for, I strongly suggest you actually reset the printing system on your MBP before trying each of the above options. To do this:

1. Got to Apple > System Preferences
2. Click on the Printers & Scanners preference pane
3. Right-click on the list of printers on the left-hand side and select *Reset printing system...*
4. At the next prompt, click on the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button

**Remember:** Make sure when you add the printer back that you use the CUPS option and not the AirPrint option. (Don't worry, you should still be able to print to your Brother printer from your iPhone and iPad).

<sup>1</sup>Not to be confused with your Mac computer. See [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) for more info. You can obtain your printer's MAC address from its configuration menu.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and effort with my problem!  I will try these possible solutions.  My Brother printer is a MFC-9130CW.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my answer, but this issue is prevalent in their Multi Function Centre models. So, telling me it's an MFC-9130CW fits 100% with my experience on this issue. Good luck with it all - it's a bit of a PITA to troubleshoot because the symptoms are so intermittent!

Comment: So next time I should buy what type of color Laser printer?

Comment: Ah well, it's a bit of a blame game. Apple and Brother blame each other. The fact is, one network I troubleshooted involved both Macs and Windows machines printing to both Brother and Canon printers with absolutely no problems until one day the Brother printers became glitchy with the Macs. It took me a while to diagnose that they had changed their routers and the problems only started after that. After some lengthy sessions with Brother, we identified the *IGMP* issue. We replaced the routers (cheaper than replacing multiple Brother MFCs) and all was good again.

Comment: TBH, the routers they did have were rather dodgy to begin with. However, even before replacing the routers, the Canon printers had no issues with either the Macs or Windows machines. So it really means that it was isolated down to an issue between the Macs and Brother MFC printers, but nevertheless an issue that was resolved by replacing routers and not by reconfiguring the Macs or printers. Go figure.